# Where i can see my console logs on localhost and when the function is deployed?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

i am using azure functions written in nodejs.

I have this azure function

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const title = req.body.title;
    console.log('title', title);
    if (title) {
        req.body.completed = false;
        context.bindings.outputDocument = req.body;
        context.res = {
            body: { success: true, message: `Todo added successfully` }
        };
    } else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: { success: false, message: `Please add title field` }
        };
    }
};
```

and the binding

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "outputDocument",
      "databaseName": "xxx",
      "collectionName": "items",
      "createIfNotExists": false,
      "connectionStringSetting": "xxx",
      "partitionKey": "/all",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

locally when i run

```
func host start
```

i don't see my console log statement.

How can i see on localhost ?

And where i need to go in my azure portal to see the logs there after deployment.

I tried to go in Function App - open my function and there the azure function but i can't see any logs there...

Comment: It should be visible, if not add a debug point

Comment: Why not? Based on linux or windows?

Comment: You can have a look of my answer.:)

Comment: I am on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i see on localhost ?
>
> And where i need to go in my azure portal to see the logs there after
> deployment.
>
> I tried to go in Function App - open my function and there the azure
> function but i can't see any logs there...

Of course, you can get the log files on local. I assume you are based on windows, then just edit the host.json like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

And go to

`C:\Users\yourusernameonlocal\AppData\Local\Temp\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Function\yourfunctionname`

After that you will see the log files.:)

Comment: Which property here configures the enabling of console logs in my app ?

Comment: @sdsd "fileLoggingMode": "always",

Comment: Thank you.Do you know maybe how can i watch for changes in my app ? When i change something in azure functions i need to restart the server to take my maked changes

Comment: @sdsd What do you mean 'watch for changes in my app'?

Comment: Something like nodemon in nodejs.

Comment: I posted ny new question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65995670/how-can-i-watch-for-changes-in-my-azure-functions   Please take a look and comment if you know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should probably resolve your issue.

[Azure Functions JavaScript developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#write-trace-output-to-logs):

> Don't use console.log to write trace outputs. Because output from console.log is captured at the function app level, it's not tied to a specific function invocation and isn't displayed in a specific function's logs.